# spam: Bitcoin address

Tags: spam

Someone deposited money into my blockchain wallet but says I must check on my Bitcoin address spam. Where is that on Blockchain because it does not appear on my transactions.

Comment: "Bitcoin address spam" isn't a thing, as far as I know.  You should ask them for clarification.

Comment: Could you modify your title to make it a bit more clear what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Bit unclear, but sounds like nonsense. Put your address into a bitcoin explorer (like blocktrail.com) and have a look at all the transacions (hopefully 1 or none). Make sure there are a few confirmations before assuming it's your money. If you're being scammed they might be sending you something with a too low fee, which might never confirm.